# AWS Lambda chaining best practice

Tags: amazon-web-services, lambda, aws-api-gateway, aws-step-functions

I'm looking a solution for my problem and maybe someone could give me some ideas.
I have a `API Gateway` plugged to a `aws lambda` A.
I have to handle cases like this:

1. Lambda A should call lambda B and if there are any results, return to the API Gateway.
2. Lambda A should call lambda B and if no results, it will call lambda C, and then return whatever the results are to the `APi Gateway`.

So, my problem is how to chain these lambdas, because I don't want to have a huge lambda.
At first, I thought about using `Step Functions` except that this works in a asynchronous mode, so no good for my case. I know I can do a lambda to call the step function and  wait for the result, but I don't like this solution.

Any ideas  for a nice solution ?

Thanks.

C.C.

Comment: Have you looked at using SNS between 2 lambda functions? If the subsequent lambda functions are small, why not invoke them directly using `lambda_client.invoke(FunctionName="")`?

Comment: Invoke the child Lambda functions directly from the parent, using a synchronous invocation. Be careful about the timeout of the parent because it will have to be large enough to accommodate the launch of a child Lambda container plus its processing.

Comment: Actually I don't really like this solution because I will have 2 tightly coupled lambdas and I will pay the execution of the first lambda for the wait.

Comment: Lambda cost is low, but agreed this is not an ideal solution. Perhaps reconsider merging the code into a single Lambda.

Comment: @kriishna the lambdas are not very small, so I want to separate the have the smallest lambda possible

Comment: Publish your message from the first lambda function to an SNS topic and subscribe the SNS topic to the second lambda function. SNS will ensure that your lambda will be invoked at least once. If your second lambda lambda function can't be invoked for some reason (like you hit concurrent execution limit), SNS will wait for the resource to be freed and invokes the lambda for you.

Comment: are your use-cases represented by a single API enpoint or multiple enpoints (i.e. each lambda `x` has it's own endpoint `x`)? how these lambdas are being deployed (any constrains here)?

Comment: What does each Lambda do? If the entire workflow finishes real fast, I don't see the reason why you'd want to split the whole logic into several Lambdas.

Comment: I have one API using these 3 lambdas. SO I think using SNS is not possible since I need a response after invoking the API Gateway. Maybe the solution is to mix them together in one single lambda.

Answer (score 3):

> You can use invoke lambda with "async await" here is docs:

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/Lambda.html#invoke-property

> For asynchronous call:
>   https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/Lambda.html#invokeAsync-property

Answer (score 1):

Really B & C are apis that A is calling

Put lambda B & C behind another api gateway, using IAM auth.
Give A rights to call that Api via your IAM Role.

- Now Your external clients call A via whatever auth scheme.
- A is free to call B or C via api (url as parameter perhaps)
- A can return results to caller

For a more granular approach, you can have B/C as their own api gateways, meaning your have decoupled them fully

MiniEdit:
For something like this I'd also consider using the Lambda Function URLs now:  https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/lambda-urls.html

Comment: Might be interesting to see API Gateway act as the broker between the Lambdas. If API Gateway leverages the new Open API 3.0 "Links" specification, this could be the interface for Lambda A to instruct API Gateway on how to route (i.e. chain) the response payload. Benefit is a reduction in RTT, minimal Lambda execution time, and complete Lambda decoupling.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [AWS Step Function](https://aws.amazon.com/step-functions/) to manage coordination between AWS lambda functions.

Comment: It does not works either. Invoking the step functions is asynchronous.

Comment: Starting from November 2020 you can use Express Step Functions: https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/compute/new-synchronous-express-workflows-for-aws-step-functions/